# Row blocked or table blocked when using a TransactionScope c# object?

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I have the following code:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
 {
      DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
      if (da.UpdateRecord(recordId))
      {
           ts.Complete();
      }
 }
```

what happens when my code is executing "da.UpdateRecord(recordId)", the row with id = "recordId" is blocked for the rest of the requests until I execute "ts.Complete" ? or the entire table is blocked ?

Thanks in advance,
German.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the Database. If you are using SQL Server, then any row or table level lock is released when `ts.Complete();` is executed.

Regarding whether it will be a row level lock or higher, SQL Server will not necessarily default to row level locking - it may use page level or table level locks.

The default isolation level of a new `TransactionScope()` object is **read serializable**. This may not be what you need for your situation and also this default is allegedly prone to deadlocks and not considered useful in general.

> The  `TransactionScope`’s default constructor defaults the isolation
>   level to `Serializable` and the timeout to `1 minute`. In SQL Server
>   SERIALIZABLE transactions are rarely useful and extremely
>   deadlock-prone.

**Source:** MSDN Blog - [Using new TransactionScope() Considered Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information, so, what do you suggest in order to support transaccionability since as far as I understand using a TransactionScope object isnt the best practise...

Maybe setting a lower isolation level ?, in this case which one do you think ?

In order to answer this question please consider a simple scenario in which you are adding an object Person and two more inserts related to this person to the database and you wanna keep this inserts inside a transactional block.

Thanks!